# Print on the default printer through tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, printing

I am developing an integrated Android application with a web service TomCat and laboratory (Eclipse Java EE) she arrived at a satisfactory level, performing queries, impressions on the default printer, all quiet, but as I get the service for Tomcat he does not perform printing it is as if there is no printer connected to the server.

The code below is used to perform printing when I am providing the service directly from Eclipse.

```
try{
InputStream prin = new ByteArrayInputStream(textoimp.getBytes());

INPUT_STREAM docFlavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;

SimpleDoc documentoTexto = new SimpleDoc(prin, docFlavor, null);

PrintService impressora = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService(); // pega a impressora padrao 

PrintRequestAttributeSet printerAttributes = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();

printerAttributes.add(new JobName("Impressao", null));

printerAttributes.add(OrientationRequested.PORTRAIT);

printerAttributes.add(MediaSizeName.ISO_A4); // informa o tipo de folha

DocPrintJob printJob = ((PrintService) impressora).createPrintJob(); //the error occurs here , the printer is null

try{

printJob.print(documentoTexto, (PrintRequestAttributeSet)printerAttributes);//try to print

}

catch(PrintException e){ 

e.printStackTrace();
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Não foi possível realizar a impressão !!", "Erro", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE); 

} 

prin.close(); 

} 

catch(Exception e){

e.printStackTrace();
return false;

}
```

But when the service is running within the Tomcat it does not work, can anyone help me?

Comment: 'It does not work' - please provide details. What exactly does not work, any exception stack trace? Btw: Using Swing dialogs (JOptionPane) in a background webservice seems wrong...

Comment: The quest to make the default printer always wrong because the returns null when the WS this in Tomcat. You're right about the JOptionPane , sorry , it's because I'm starting now .

Comment: Did you check some of those questions available on SO? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17390207/printing-is-not-working-in-tomcat-when-i-start-server-with-services-mscfrom-cl

Answer (score 0):

Answered by Arjan says Tijms , had a question answered on SO and I had not seen , I thank the friend .
Below the link of the answer :

[Printing is not working in tomcat, when i start server with services.msc(From client side we could not print )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17390207/printing-is-not-working-in-tomcat-when-i-start-server-with-services-mscfrom-cl)